# finding servlet url-pattern

Tags: web-services, spring, servlets, web.xml, url-pattern

What should be the servlet url-pattern for following URL Paths:

```
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@7bbf68a9: defining beans [restfulController,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver#0,policyView,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Mar 5, 2012 11:51:05 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/restservice/number] onto handler 'restfulController'
Mar 5, 2012 11:51:05 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/restservice/number.*] onto handler 'restfulController'
Mar 5, 2012 11:51:05 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/restservice/number/] onto handler 'restfulController'
Mar 5, 2012 11:51:05 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/restservice/policyA] onto handler 'restfulController'
Mar 5, 2012 11:51:05 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/restservice/policyA.*] onto handler 'restfulController'
Mar 5, 2012 11:51:05 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/restservice/policyA/] onto handler 'restfulController'
Mar 5, 2012 11:51:05 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
```

I have tried /restservice*, /restservice/* but only /* is working.

Comment: This should work - can you should your Servlet mappings?

Comment: @home nope! /service/* didn't work. Am I missing any other servlet element in web.xml.

Comment: @home <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>policy</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

Comment: Hm, that should really work. Did you try it with something else than 'service', just a guess?

Comment: @home I have updated my question. Please read it again.

Comment: @Bozho I have updated my question with more detail. Please go through it again.

Comment: Apologies, I do not have that much experience with restful spring - added the 'spring' tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve it by removing /restservice/ from my Spring Controller.

Answer (score 1):

You should use /*.

If you use "/restservice/*", you must call <>/restservice/restservice/ ...
You may try using a subfix instead of a prefix.. such as *.do or something.

Comment: Using  "/restservice/*", and calling <>/restservice/restservice/ ...  didn't work either.